# How to apply 2D active contours (snakes) in 3D image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to apply a snake method on a 3D image with no sucess. To my understanding, MATLAB's "activecontours" can be applied to 3D images but it seems that it fits a surface (balloon) into an object, instead of a single contour (snake). Or at least it seems to repeat the seed contour slice by slice, instead of fitting a single countour into a 3D object, because the end result is the whole 3D image segmented. I am looking for an active contour that has 3D awareness, as suggested by the following figure:

[image: Expected outcome of 3D snake]

If the seed contour is the blue contour (slightly in perspective as to see it is a contour), I want the final snake to be the green one, as it fits the closest and easiest edge, instead of the red one, which would happen if I simply applied a 2D snake onto a slice of the 3D image coplanar with the seed contour. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks like you want to apply the snake to each 2D slice, then find the “correct” slice. For each slice you can compute the distance to the originally selected slice, and the amount of deformation applied, and use those two somehow to find the best result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Judging by my image that would work, i.e., when the blue circle is perfectly alligned with the thin tube. The problem is when that is not the case, which could lead to extremely tilted green circles, instead of one surrounding the opening of the thin tube. I realize now I may have drawn a convenient picture, but if you have any more advice please let me know!

Comment: How about segmenting the whole structure out (I don’t even know what imaging modality you are using, but I guess you don’t need much more than thresholding and some filtering to get there), the identifying the transition plane between the thin part and the thick part?

Comment: My image is already binary in fact, so no problem getting there. But I am out of ideas about identifying the transition plane... One detail in case it's important, there are actually other thin tubes connected to the thick part, in other regions. I do have all the blue circles, so I know the "insertion" locations, and I could define a volume around each one to analyse, but I still don't know how could I identify the opening in each volume :/